# Not properly render image from Django model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I am making a simple app(Django version 1.11+python3.5+). I want to show images on my homepage(web app) from Django models. I can upload successfully from Django admin panel. But image cant renders properly. The image does not show in the homepage. This is my HTML file.

```
{% extends "shop/base.html" %}
{% block content_area %}
{% for name in products %}
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
    <div class="main_content_sidebar">
        <div class="content_title">
            <h2>{{name.product_name}}</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="image_space">
            <img src="{{name.product_image.url}}" class="img-thumbnail" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="content_p">
            <p>Retail Price:{{name.product_retail_price}}</p>
            <p>Quantity: {{name.product_quantity}}</p>
            <p>Date: {{name.product_sell_date}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

this is mysite(project)>>urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from django.conf import settings
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^shop/',include('shop.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This is my models.py file.

```
class ProductsName(models.Model):
    product_name=models.CharField('name', max_length=50)
    product_retail_price=models.IntegerField('retail price TAKA')
    product_quantity = models.IntegerField('quantity')
    product_sell_date=models.DateTimeField('buy date', auto_now_add=True)
    product_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='upload/', blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name
```

setting.py file

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.11.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = ''

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'shop.apps.ShopConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Dhaka'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'shop/images/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

When I visit my homepage, I can't see any image. But I see image link If I open my browser dev tools.
[chrome dev tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vW808.png)

if I click that image link from chrome dev tool. I got an[django doesn/t found that image url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35MdK.png) error.

Also my folder structure is:

mysite
shop
manage.py
path_to
db.sqlite3

Comment: As an advice, never post the secret key in public

Comment: Ok. I removed it.

Comment: What is the folder project structure, the media folder is located in?

Comment: Also my folder structure is:
 
mysite
shop
manage.py
path_to
db.sqlite3

Comment: The media folder is under shop>media?

Comment: shop > images> upload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the your `MEDIA_ROOT` is not being served and Django cannot append the correct url. In your project urls.py add the following at the end:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And in the setttings.py add the correct paths for:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'path_to_/media_folder')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Comment: I added this code after I had founded the same issue. Image doesn/t show .

Comment: mysite urls.py from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from django.conf import settings
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^shop/',include('shop.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Comment: And what is the setting for media_root and media_url in the settings.py file? @AsaduzzamanSohel

Comment: This line `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'path_to_/media_folder')
` is now the problem, using your Django Project folder structure, where is the media file located? Is under the app folder? If under the app folder, the path would be `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'app_name/media')`. 
`

Comment: Use the actual name of the app in the `app-name` is that is where the media folder is located

Comment: shop > images> upload

Comment: Please create a folder called `media` under the shop and move the folder `upload` and its contents to it so that we have shop>media>upload. Then modify the `MEDIA_ROOT` in settings.py as follows `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'shop/media')`.Then try running or uploading the image again. @AsaduzzamanSohel

Comment: Nothing changed. When I went to page source and click image link , I found  this issue.

Comment: Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/media/upload/1497821.jpg
'media/upload/1497821.jpg' could not be found

Comment: Are you still using `<img src="{% static name.product_image.url %}" class="img-thumbnail" alt="">` to load the image? If so edit it to be `<img src="{{ name.product_image.url }}" class="img-thumbnail" alt="">` @AsaduzzamanSohel

Comment: Thank you. Now Image is showing on my homepage. Could you please tell me What happened in my code?

Comment: When in development, you use Django to serve the static/media files, that was why we edited the mysite.urls and added `if settings.DEBUG:....`, The reason why Django could not load your media despite saving the correct path in the Db was because the media urls was not properly configured, after we added the media_root and media_url, we were telling Django to use the media url, that is why now the url for the picture includes `/media/shop/upload/.....jpg`. But you had used  `static` tag to load the media, that is why it was showing `../static/media/...`. Only use that to load static files

Comment: In production, your media files will be served with `Nginx`. Also make sure you setup the static folder as the media folder. For now shop>static and the add `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'shop/static')` and `STATIC_URL = /static/`. If you happen to want put in a different location, make sure you add the correct path in settings.py

Comment: can you vote my question, if you think this is userful?